# Coordinate-free B.Feix's construction of a hyperkähler metric

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hyperkaehler

In the 2001's paper 'Hyperkähler metrics on cotangent bundles' B.Feix gives a construction of a hyperkähler metric on a neighbourhood of zero section in $T^*X$ where $X$ is a real analytic Kähler manifold.

As for me, this construction is awful. It's not difficult to understand the general steps of it and I'm really inspired by them but if you look at details it's just awful. Almost everything is written in local coordinates without explaining why everything can be glued globally, the article starts with choosing a local antiholomorphic involution on $X$ without mentioning it properly, she calls 'the complexified Kähler form on $X^\mathbb C$' a form which is not the analytic continuation of the Kähler form on $X$ etc.

I've spent several days trying to rewrite the paper in a coordinate-free way changing some steps as it'd be more similar to constructions of a Kähler metric on a neighbourhood of zero section in $T^*X$ where $X$ is a real analytic Riemannian manifold due to Lempert, Szöke and Guillemin, Stenzel. I'm not completely successful yet, though. So I ask, perhaps this paper is already written? I know about D.Kaledin's paper but his approach is rather different, I want something which looks like Feix's construction.